# Sharing data between es6 modules

Tags: module, global-variables, sharedpreferences, ecmascript-6

Is there a place where es6 modules (jspm/system.js & babel) can share data with each other (not window):?

Ex: I have a parser module for http query strings. I use it at startup to choose which program to run (one html file running many programs). I also use it in the selected program to get flag values for running it.  Example: triangles or squares, what number of them, world coord system ... etc.

How do I share the result of the query string parse between the startup module and the various modules needing the flag data? Is there a special "exports" data space for modules?

I can just re-parse, no big deal, but in the future, I may want to store results of long computations so they can be shared. I can also pass the data to the modules in an "init" procedure, but this can be awkward.

Comment: Just `export` it? You can export data as well, not only functions.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking at passing data to a global var from one module and having another module read from it here's an example of a simple data store module.

in SimpleStore.js

```
var _store = {};

class SimpleStore {
   constructor(props) {
      if (props) { 
         _store = props;
      }
    }
    getContent() {
        return _store;
    }
}
export default SimpleStore
```

and in Module A we'll store something

```
import SimpleStore from './SimpleStore'

class A {
    constructor(props) {
        new SimpleStore({foo: 'bar'});
    }
}
```

in Module B we'll get that content

```
import SimpleStore from './SimpleStore'

class B {
    constructor(props) {
        var content = new SimpleStore().getContent();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you can easily change the content of `_store` when instantiating SimpleStore ie. `new SimpleStore('replace the original content')`

That's where libraries like [IMMUTABLE.js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) can be useful. Also as example check out the store modules used with [React Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-stores) and [Redux](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/Store.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should make a 3rd "config" module, say "C", so that "A" and "B" both depend on it. This module loads/caches/exposes the configuration data to the other modules.