# ES6: share data between modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

To share data between modules, a usual pattern is to capsulate the data into a common module and import it in other modules.

In my case the data to be shared is a logger, which need to be initialized before used. I call `init()` at the entry point of my application.

```
// main.js

let logger = require('@my/logger');
logger.init({...});

let xxx = require('./moduleX');
let yyy = require('./moduleY');
```

In other modules, the initialized logger can be used:

```
// moduleX.js

let logger = require('@my/logger');
const log = logger('moduleX');

function x() {
  log.debug('some msg');
}
```

Above code works well in node.js. But if I change to ES6 module syntax, it doesn't work because ES6 module import is hoisted.

```
// main.js

import {logger} from '@my/logger';
logger.init({...});          // this line is run after import moduleX
import {x} from './moduleX';

// moduleX.js

import {logger} from '@my/logger';
const log = logger('moduleX');        // logger is not initialized !

export function x() {
  log.debug('some msg');
}
```

With ES6 module, how can I initialize some data and share them to other modules?

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956636/sharing-data-between-es6-modules) but the answer doesn't fit my case.

Update:

Some answers suggest to put the code which access shared data into function so that the code isn't invoked immediately at module load. But what if I really need to access it during module loading? I updated my code to demonstrate the use case -- it would be too trivial to call `logger(name)` in every function if not make `log` as module scope const.

Comment: Why don't you just create another file `initializeLogger.js` where you call `logger.init` and import that one in `main.js`?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I have thought of this way, but it needs anther file, looks not  concise enough to me. However, it seems to be the only way to solve it. Could you write it an answer so that I accept it?

Comment: What initialisation does the logger need before you call `logger(…)`? Wouldn't only `log.debug(…)` need to wait?

Comment: @Bergi Output destination, application name, etc. You may said it's not necessary to do that for a logger. I'm asking for a general pattern to handle this kind of requirement: initialize an object and share it to every modules.

Comment: @aleung: Hm, the "similar question" you linked seems to answer this already. But I've written an explicit answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solve it in the way that @PaoloMoretti mentioned in his comment.

Write a module in my app to init the logger for my app:

```
// logger_init.js
import {logger} from '@my/logger';
logger.init({...});
```

Import the initialization module once at the entry point of application, prior to imports of any other modules that use logger as well. It guarantees that the initialization is done before loading other modules.

```
// main.js
import './logger_init'; 
import {x} from '@my/other_module';
import {y} from './module_in_myapp';
```

Other modules can use initialized logger directly:

```
// @my/other_module

import {logger} from '@my/logger';
const log = logger('moduleX');       // logger has been initialized

export function x() {
  log.debug('some msg');
}
```

The dependency tree is:

```
                           <init>
myapp --+--> logger_init ------------> @my/logger
        |                       <use>   ↑ 
        +--> module_in_myapp -----------+
        |                       <use>   |
        +--> @my/other_module ----------+
```

Why I don't adopt the way that add a wrapper module which init and return a logger (as Bergi's answer) is because the modules uses logger could be reusable modules not in my application.

Comment: You can even do only `import './logger_init';` for side effects

Answer (score 1):

> A logger, which need to be initialized before used. What if I need to access it during module loading?

Make an extra module with an initialised logger:

```
// main.js
import {x as xxx} from './moduleX';
import {y as yyy} from './moduleY';
```

```
// logger_ready.js
import {logger} from '@my/logger';
logger.init({…});
export default logger;
```

```
// moduleX.js
import logger from 'logger_ready';
const log = logger('moduleX');        // logger is initialized here!

export function x() {
  log.debug('some msg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide some entry points to your xxx.js and yyy.js modules or even make them as functions.

```
// main.js
import {logger} from '@my/logger';
import * as xxx from './xxx';

logger.init({...});

xxx.run();

// xxx.js
import {logger} from '@my/logger';
export function run () {
   logger.debug('In xxx');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have each module that has a dependency on some initialisation routine return a function that can be executed manually to invoke its functionality, rather than expose that functionality as an immediate side-effect of importing it. For example, in `xxx.js`:

```
// xxx.js
export default function (log) {
    log('xxx');
}
```

Then place all initialisation operations within an entry file and invoke the modules defined in the above way *after* these operations are complete:

```
// main.js
import xxx from './xxx';
import {logger} from '@my/logger';
logger.init({...});
xxx(logger);
```

> But what if I really need to access it during module loading?

Please see the amended code examples above. Pass the instance of `logger` to the function exported by each module.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I really need to access it during module loading? Please read my question update.

Comment: _Why_ does it need to run immediately on import? Use delayed execution as in my answer and pass in the instance of logger to each module function? (I have updated my answer.)

Comment: I've updated my code. In module I need to call `log = logger('moduleX'); ` to set logger name to module name. If not make a module scope const, it will be too trivial to set logger name in every function. BTW, in your amended code passing logger as function argument is another favor. I personally like to keep the logger out of argument list.

Comment: Either you will have to amend how `logger` works such that it can be invoked like `logger('moduleX')` prior to initialisation (then the example in your question will work), or you will you have to use the method I have outlined in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

After experiments, found that the [BroadcastChannel api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) is perfect to share data or events easily between different es6 modules, tabs, workers, frames...

We can pass objects or arrays by using json stringify there too:

To send datas:

```
new BroadcastChannel('myapp_section8').postMessage('Hello world!')
```

Example receiving, from another module:

```
new BroadcastChannel('myapp_section8').addEventListener('message', function(e){
  console.log(e.data) 
})
```

It avoid to use any DOM elements to *dispatchEvent*, it simplify stuffs **a lot**!